# Where can I find a C# implementation of SHA-1 not using the built in libraries?

Tags: c#, sha1

I am trying to rewrite the SHA-1 algorithm for parallelization in a personal project of mine.  Just wondering if anyone knows where I can find a C# implementation of the actual mathematical  operations to perform the hash, not just the `System.Security.Cryptography` function.

Comment: You could use reflector and look at the code in SHA1Managed class.

Comment: 8 years later, I have the same question, and find a dead link ... Let's bump this.

Answer (score 1):

[FIPS PUB 180](http://www.itl.nist.gov/fipspubs/fip180-1.htm). I'm not going to comment whether rolling your own implementation of any crypto algorithm is a good idea...

Comment: I'm not going to comment whether calling a Hash algorithm as crypto algorithm a good idea :p

Comment: I'm not rewriting the logic of it, just making its execution parallel.

Comment: The link is dead